# Building Angular2 into dist - app: dist/app correct?

Tags: angular

I changed the configuration so the code will be build in dist directory. Everything works fine. But I had to change this line:

```
  var map = {
    'app':                        'dist/app', // 'dist',
    .....
  };
```

Is **dist/app** correct? In several documentations I saw only **dist**.

[image]

Comment: please add your application directory structure

Comment: Done, 9 more to go...

Comment: var map = {
    'app':   'dist'
  };